# How to backup programs to DVD

Tags: installation, dvd

Is there any way to backup installed programs to DVD.
For example when I will install new Ubuntu to install software from the disk and not from the Internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yeah you can use [aptoncd](http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/) for it

  ***APTonCD** is a tool with a graphical interface which allows you to

  create one or more CDs or DVDs (you choose the type of media) with all

  of the packages you've downloaded via APT-GET or APTITUDE, creating a

  removable repository that you can use on other computers. **APTonCD** will

  also allow you to automatically create media with all of your .deb

  packages located in one specifier repository, so that you can install

  them into your computers without the need for an Internet connection.*

[image]

**Installation**

```
sudo apt-get install aptoncd
```

This will work only if you didnt clear the apt cache

Comment: Thats Awesome!!! i didn knew anything like this exists