# Copying installed software from ubuntu 12.04 to ubuntu 12.04 CD

Tags: software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to backup programs to DVD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116209/how-to-backup-programs-to-dvd)

I have downloaded some software via the Ubuntu Software Center and I would like to copy this software to an ubuntu CD. Is that possible? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: Do you just want the packages ? Or do you want a backup of your whole system ?